# Font missing with Crystal Reports generated PDF

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, barcode

I have a Crystal Report 8.5 file, that I need to export to PDF.

That report contains a field that I need to represent as Bar Code. To achieve that I use a TrueType font.

- If I open the generated PDF file on that machine I see the bar code.
- But if I open it from another machine that doesn't have the font installed, I see only numbers.

How can I assure that the codebar is visible on the PDF even if the computer doesn't have the font installed?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to include a font, you can generate an image and call it via HTTP.

The barcode below is generated using an online barcode generator courtesy of WASP:
`http://www.waspbarcode.com/services/waspbarcode/barcodegen.ashx?symbology=Code128&code=font_missing_31301980`

[image: wasp font_missing_31301980]

Steps for Report:

1. Create blank JPG using MS Paint. Resize without aspect ratio checked on.
2. Insert image placer holder such as 50x323 PNG into Crystal Report
3. Right-click on graphic and select Format Graphic...

[image: Format Graphic...]

4. Click on Picture tab, click on Formula, Enter Formula

[image: Format Editor, Picture tab]

5. Create a formula where like the URL above. You want to retrieve the barcode data from the database and concatenate the prefix and barcode field together:

`"http://www.waspbarcode.com/services/waspbarcode/barcodegen.ashx?symbology=Code128&code=" + {table.barcode_field}`

[image: report result]

*Take care to use your own online barcode generator.* WASP service may not work if people starting abusing the service and generate too many barcodes for reports.

You can also generate [Code 3 of 9 barcodes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146336/Creating-a-Code-Barcode-using-HTML-CSS-and-Java) using HTML only, but I haven't tried in Crystal Report formula yet.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It's a good idea. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the Bar Code font installed on the machine that is rendering the report if you are exporting to PDF because Crystal Reports does not embed fonts due to licensing issues.

However, you can print to a PDF printer, and select the option to embed the fonts into the file.

There are issues embedding fonts with 8.5 and SAP is not going to be very helpful as it is such an old version.

Comment: I need the barcode on the PDF to be seen even if the computer doesn't have the font already installed

Answer (score 0):

You have to ***embed*** the barcode font into the PDF!

Very likely the following has happened:

1. The PDF is generated on a machine that (obviously) has the mentioned TrueType barcode font installed locally, but the barcode font isn't embedded into the PDF.
2. Hence the same machine can still display that barcode correctly (because the font is available from the machine's local installation).
3. The same barcode font is NOT installed on your $other machine.
4. Hence $other machine cannot display that barcode correctly because it has to use a substitute font.

To rectify that situation, you have two options:

1. Install that barcode font onto every single machine which will ever have to process, display or print that PDF. This is the worse alternative.
2. Make your PDF generating software embed the barcode font into the PDF. Then you do not need to care about any machine that ever opens, displays, processes or prints the PDF. This is the better alternative!

Comment: And how can I set Crystal Reports to Embed the font on the PDF?

Comment: I suggest you close this question by accepting + upvoting a good answer (if you think there is one). Then ask a new question specifically about *"Crystal Reports + embedding fonts into a PDF"*.

Comment: The original question was how to get Crystal Reports to do it. Your answer isn't a good one if it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: @JimLutz: Don't teach me (a year later) what the original question was: because I did edit the original question to make it better readable and more comprehensive (within 20 minutes after it first appeared). Then I upvoted the question because in its essence it is an excellent one. After that, I proceeded to answer it as good as I could at the time without having access to the Crystal Report software myself.

Comment: @JimLutz: My answer is as valid as it can be. Your comment isn't a good one: because even ***IF*** the question was specifically about *"how to get Crystal Report to do it"*, it would have been about how to do it for a ***Crystal Reports 8.5*** file. Big difference....

Answer (score 0):

I had done this, so whenever you want the custom font style in crystal report, you have to install that font in server machine where your application host.

So if font is available, then report will map the font style and display as normal font.

**There is one rule when you want other than standard font** : as you installed font in your local machine to check pdf, the same process you will done on to the application server where your application are host or simply say the location (means server) / computer of your crystal report's physical files.

To show bar-code value in your crystal report, you just need to choose font in the format text of controls. Reports automatically display that, if it find the font, other wise gives error of font missing or not show properly bar-code section.

Comment: The OP stated in the question: "How can I assure that the codebar is visible on the PDF even if the computer doesn't have the font installed?"

Answer (score 0):

If you use a barcode image library, such as this [barcode 3 of 9 image creating library for Crystal Reports](http://www.avapose.com/dotnet_barcode_crystal_report/code39_generator.shtml), you will need not install font to each computers.